# Is there any free software to report iOS app usage statistics to a server?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, usage-statistics

What I did with a non-iOS program once was fetch an HTML page that had a hit counter on it.

However for my iOS stuff, I'd like to get some actual device info, sort of like what comScore and Flurry do.

But has anyone written any freeware (open source) that I can use for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this guy:

https://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/

Not quite open source, but free and pretty stable.

Answer (score 1):

How about flurry, http://www.flurry.com/

We've been use it for over years. It's not open source but still easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Cobub Razor which is open source, their website [Cobub Developer Center](http://dev.cobub.com)